# Laravel 5.2 lock controller for some users

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I want to lock **AccountsController** for all the users expect users **for admin users**..

> For Exampe:

`Auth::user() -> roll != 'Admin'` then close the **AccountsController**..

***AccountsController Construct Code:***

```
    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

Comment: You should create your own middleware to check the logged in user's role. Have a go and post back with what you've tried if you get stuck.

Comment: what about using `if(Auth::user() -> roll == 'Admin')` in the controller?

Comment: It's not recommended that you check permissions on the business logic from the controller (speration of concerns), but you can do so... You can even restrict per method.

Comment: Well I'm sure something like that would work, give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware) is a completely valid solution for this, but I have switched to [Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#gates) for this type of situation. Gate is a bit more convenient to use. I use roles and permissions and a `hasRole` method to manage the level of access, but if your system is simple you can easily just have a `isAdmin` method on your `User` model that checks a flag in the database.

### Middleware

Create you custome middleware.

**AuthenticateAdmin.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class AuthenticateAdmin {

  protected $auth;

  public function __construct(Guard $auth)
  {
    $this->auth = $auth;
  }

  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    if ($this->auth->user()->hasRole('admin'))
    {
     return $next($request);
    }
  }
}
```

Add that to your Kernel.

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.admin' => Middleware\AuthenticateAdmin::class,
];
```

Then you can use the middleware in your controllers.

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('auth.admin');
}
```

### Gate

With Gate you add you define your policy in AuthServiceProvider

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot(GateContract $gate)
{
    parent::registerPolicies($gate);

    $gate->define('user-admin', function($user){
        return $user->hasRole('admin');
    });
}
```

Then add it to your controller or where ever you need it.

**Controller.php**

```
public function show($slug)
{
  if (Gate::allows('user-admin')){
    return $yes;
  }
  return $no;
}
```